# MySQL import a dumped database results in different values

Tags: mysql, import, export, double

i have the following task: 
- dump a database (named live) as DBBackup_TIMESTAMP.sql
- import the created dump into another database (named test) 
- dump the database test again as diff.sql

This works like charm. The last step is to diff the two dumps (DBBackup_TIMESTAMP.sql and diff.sql) to validate the dumped DBBackup_TIMESTAMP.sql file and save it on a backup space.

PROBLEM: 
The two files are different. 
In the live DB there are some rows in a table which have -0.000 as double value and in the test database the value is 0.000 for the specific rows.

Question: 
Is there a way to force mysql to import the values -0.000 as they are into the test db? (yes i know 0.000 is correct and -0.000 is not that correct, but the requirement is to have -0.000 in the db's)

MySQL Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

Dump command:

```
mysqldump -u $MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS -h 127.0.0.1 --port=$PORT --skip-comments --databases my_db > $FILE_NAME
```

Import command:

```
mysql -u $MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS -h 127.0.0.1 --port=$MYSQL_PORT_BACKUP < $DUMP_FILE
```

Any ideas how to solve this or what could be the problem?

Would be great if anybody could help, or at least has an idea what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is documented behavior.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html says:

> An implication of the preceding issues is that if you attempt to create a replication slave by dumping table contents with mysqldump on the master and reloading the dump file into the slave, tables containing floating-point columns might differ between the two hosts.

If you need exact numeric values, use [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Further reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (Goldberg, 1991)

Comment: Thank you Bill, this information was the solution !